# SonarQube wrong reporting results

Tags: sonarqube

I use sonarqube to do the line coverage analysis, but the reporting results are fallacious.
For example for the if method below:

```
if(a != null ){ 

system.out.print("Hello");

}
```

the if condition is reported as NOT covered by unit test，which means not executed .
BUT，the logical system.out.print("Hello") inside is reported as covered by unit test. that is illogical, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a question of SonarQube but of your coverage engine. SonarQube only relays what your coverage engine reported.

That said, you're likely misinterpreting the markers in the SonarQube interface, although without a screenshot it's hard to know for certain. If you're seeing a diagonally striped marker next to the `if`, then SonarQube is telling you that the line is *partially* covered. That is, there are multiple paths through the code and only some of them are taken  in your testing. Specifically, it sounds like you are testing the path where the condition is true. I would guess you're not testing the path where the condition is false.

Comment: The real situation is that the If condition is marked as NEVER covered instead of  partially covered. What you said is certainly logical that the true case is tested , so that logic inside the if condition is marked as covered, that is logical and acceptable . Unexpectedly , the real situation is not conformed to what your guess. Likewise, what you mentioned ahead might be the cause , that the coverage engine is reporting the wrong metrics which leads to the wrong reporting of SonarQube. So, I will try to focus on the coverage engine , thanks for your kind suggestion, it is highly appreciated.